# Почему цвет менюшки не менят цвет обратно?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Я сделал скрипт, который при наведении мыши перекрашивает каждый элемент в меню в белый цвет, а при событии `mouseout` возвращается черный цвет. Однако при наведении курсора мыши другие элементы тоже перекрашиваются в белый цвет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот ссылка http://test3.testkz.ru/

```
$("#cssmenu ul li").mouseover(function() {
    $(".has-sub a span").css("color", "white");
        }).mouseout(function() {
    $(".has-sub a span").css("color", "black");
});
```

Comment: Потому что Вы селектором `$(".has-sub a span")` указали, что при наведении ВСЕ span-ы становятся белыми. Почитайте про `$(this)` в JQuery. А вообще в этом случае лучше обойтись css, применив псевдокласс `:hover`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

убери js код, и сделай это в CSS

style.css строка 567

```
#cssmenu ul li span:hover, #cssmenu ul li:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

замени на

```
#cssmenu ul li:hover > a * {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо !!! Получилось!